# Properties not visible when logging an typescript object in console

Tags: typescript

I am creating a class in typescript . Then i have created an object for the class and i have not initialized any of the properties . I have console logged it and found that the object has no properties in it .

```
public class student
{
name:string ;
}

let s=new student();

console.log(s); --> This gives empty object with no properties . This should actually give an object with all
```

properties with empty or null values

```
let s=new student();
s.name="Avinash"

console.log(s); --> This gives an object with name property and its value
```

Can some one please help me understand this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a property on a typescript class (if not initialized to anything) is just a declaration that will have no runtime behavior. We are just telling the compiler that the property is allowed to exists so we can then use it (as you do in your second sample).

This becomes evident if we look at the generated js (for es5):

TS:

```
public class student
{
  name: string;
  lastName : string = ""
}
```

JS:

```
var student = /** @class */ (function () {
    function student() {
        this.lastName = ""; // just the initialized property 
    }
    return student;
}());
```

If you want to always have the property present assign it a default, if only `undefined`

```
public class student
{
  name: string =  undefined;
  lastName : string = ""
}
let s=new student();
console.log(s); // now we have student {name: undefined, lastName: ""}
```

Comment: If i want the property to be always present . Do i have to initialize it with undenfined. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: @SaiAvinash, yup you have to explicitly initialize it unfortunately.

Comment: if i want to make it intialized with null or deafult value of its type. Is there any way ?

Comment: @SaiAvinash Again no way to do this automatically for  all properties, you need to explicitly assign them (`public class student
{
  name: string =  null;
}`. As for the default of a type, Javascript has no such concept, and Typescript tries to avoid adding expression level syntax, so you need to set the value explicitly  to whatever default you want.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs .

Answer (score 0):

You simply defined what properties the class could have. To initialize it with values use constructor method

```
class student {
    name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name= message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `MongoDb` database. I had different properties in model and schema so **make sure you've same properties**